# Type checking with try/with statements in Ocaml?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I'm implementing a mock interpreter using Ocaml. One of the mock functionalities is to evaluate a made up expression using pattern matching. **The issue is trivial and definitely fixable, but I'm trying to find a more elegant way of doing this, so read on if you're still interested!**

A snippet of my user defined type looks like this:

```
type value =
  | Val_Int of int
  | Val_Bool of bool

type expr =
  | Id of string
  | Int of int
  | Bool of bool
  | Plus of expr * expr
  | Equal of expr * expr
```

Of course, I have a function for evaluating these expressions in the form of `(string * value) list -> expr -> value`, a snippet of the function looks like this:

```
(* Ignore this helper function if you'd like *)
let rec lookup env x = match env with
  | [] -> raise (DeclarationError "Declaration Error")
  | (y,v)::env_t -> if x = y then v else lookup env_t x
;;

(* The evaluation function *)
let rec eval_expr env e = match e with
  | Id(x) -> lookup env x
  | Int(x) -> Val_Int(x)
  | Bool(x) -> Val_Bool(x)
  | Plus(x,y) ->  (try
                    let Val_Int n1 = eval_expr env x in
                    let Val_Int n2 = eval_expr env y in
                    Val_Int (n1 + n2)
                  with _ -> raise (TypeError "Type Error Plus"))
  | Equal(x,y) -> (try
                    let value n1 = eval_expr env x in
                    let value n2 = eval_expr env y in
                    Val_Bool (n1 = n2)
                  with _ -> raise (TypeError "Type Error Equal"))
;;
```

Here I'm using `try/with` statements to catch any native error types and throwing my own error `TypeError`. I'm using polymorphic variants like `Val_Int n1` to protect my variables from invalid type operations like `1 + true`, which should throw `TypeError`.

The issue is more for `Equals` expressions. `Equals` should only be evaluated when the two arguments are of the same type (i.e. both `Val_Int` or both `Val_Bool`), and throw `TypeError` if something like `Equals(Val_Int(0), Val_Bool(false))` is passed in.

With `Plus`, I'm able to explicitly define my types as `Val_Int`, so something like `Plus(Val_Int(0), Val_Bool(false))` would throw `match failure` and it would be caught by the `try/with` statement, but I can't do this for `Equals`, which could be of either `Val_Int` or `Val_Bool`. That is, something like `Equals(Val_Int(0), Val_Bool(false))` will only return `Val_Bool(false)` instead of throwing an error.

One way I could fix this is if I used `match/with` statements instead of `try/with`, like if I did something like:

```
|Equal(x,y)->(match (eval_expr env x,eval_expr env y) with
            |(Val_Int(a),Val_Int(b)) -> Val_Bool(a = b) 
            |(Val_Bool(a),Val_Bool(b)) -> Val_Bool(a = b)
            |(_,_) -> raise (TypeError "TypeError Equals"))
```

but I'm trying to find a more elegant way of doing this. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Yes, `match` is the appropriate solution.

Comment: Indeed, `match` is the appropriate solution but he wanted another way of doing it. 
Is `mock` an equivalent of `dummy` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, challenge accepted.

First of all, you don't need your type `value` since you already have `Int` and `Bool` in your expression. But you could keep this type `value` so it has a type in it, and that's what I'd do :

```
type expr =
  | Id of string
  | Int of int
  | Bool of bool
  | Plus of expr * expr
  | Equal of expr * expr

type ty = Int | Bool

(* I used the type expr but we know that we will only put Int or Bool in it *)
type value = { e : expr; t : ty }

exception DeclarationError of string
exception TypeError of string

module SMap = Map.Make (struct 
  type t = string    
  let compare = compare
end)

let rec lookup env x =
  try SMap.find x env
  with Not_found ->raise (DeclarationError "Declaration Error")
;;

let rec eval_expr env e = match e with
  | Id x -> lookup env x
  | Int _ -> {e; t = Int}
  | Bool _ -> {e; t = Bool}
  | Plus (e1, e2) -> 
    let v1 = eval_expr env e1 and
        v2 = eval_expr env e2 in
    begin
      match v1.e, v2.e with
        | Int e1, Int e2 -> {e = Int (e1 + e2); t = Int}
        | _ -> raise (TypeError "Type Error Plus")
    end
  | Equal (e1, e2) -> 
    let v1 = eval_expr env e1 and
        v2 = eval_expr env e2 in
    if v1.t = v2.t then {e = Bool (v1.e = v2.e); t = Bool}
    else raise (TypeError "Type Error Equal")
```

Yes, in that case the type is only used once, in case of an `Equal` construct, but if you want a more complex system you'll just have to add more types and it will work well.

Notice that in the `Plus` construct I match the expressions, not the types, because I need the values in it.

I took a moment to use a `Map` and not a `List` for your `lookup` function.

Answer (score 2):

Catching `Match_failure` is very poor style, you are correct to look for a cleaner way.

Here's a straightforward approach which factors out matching on values. Replace the assertions with your own error messages.

```
type value =
  | Val_Int of int
  | Val_Bool of bool

type expr =
  | Id of string
  | Int of int
  | Bool of bool
  | Plus of expr * expr
  | Equal of expr * expr

let rec lookup env x = match env with
  | [] -> assert false
  | (y,v)::env_t -> if x = y then v else lookup env_t x

let int_of_val = function
  | Val_Int n -> n
  | _ -> assert false

let val_equal a b =
  match a, b with
  | Val_Int x, Val_Int y -> x = y
  | Val_Bool x, Val_Bool y -> x = y
  | _, _ -> assert false

let rec eval_expr env = function
  | Id name -> lookup env name
  | Int n -> Val_Int n
  | Bool b -> Val_Bool b
  | Plus (x, y) ->
    Val_Int (int_of_val (eval_expr env x) +
             int_of_val (eval_expr env y))
  | Equal (x,y) ->
    Val_Bool (val_equal (eval_expr env x) (eval_expr env y))
```

Comment: I love this solution. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it would be to use mutually recursive functions :
one for the arithmetic evalution and one for the boolean evaluation.
Also, your expr type would become :

```
type expr = Arith   of aexpr
          | Boolean of bexpr

and aexpr = Int of int
          | Plus of aexpr * aexpr

and bexpr = Bool of bool
          | EqualArith of aexpr * aexpr
          | EqualBool of bexpr * bexpr
```

This way, `Plus` can only accept arithmetical expression by construction. 
Similarily you have one constructor for boolean equality, and one for arithmetical equality.
Also you have to split your evaluation function into two :

```
let rec eval_expr env = function
  | Arith e -> Val_int (eval_aexpr e)
  | Boolean b -> Val_bool (eval_bexpr b)

and eval_aexpr = function
  | Int i    -> i
  | Plus i,j -> (eval_aexpr i) + (eval_aexpr j)

and eval_bexpr = function
  | Bool b        -> b
  | EqualArith (e1,e2) -> 
      let v_e1 = eval_aexpr e1 and v_e2 = eval_aexpr e2 in
      v_e1 = v_e2
  | EqualBool (e1,e2) -> 
      let v_e1 = eval_bexpr e1 and v_e2 = eval_bexpr e2 in
      v_e1 = v_e2
```

This way of coding allows you to only modify your artithmetical (resp, boolean) evaluator when you add arithmetical(resp boolean) constructions